# Unable to update relationship filed with multiple ids

Tags: wordpress, axios, advanced-custom-fields

I'm using a acf with acf-to-rest-api on my wp setup.

I've a ACF relatioship field labeled 'Terms'. 
When i try to save terms using a wp api from my react app, it only works when there is one item in array. if i send multiple items in array, it doesn't update and remove any old selection.

I found this on their github, but cant figure out what is wrong in my code.  https://github.com/airesvsg/acf-to-rest-api/issues/257

My code to send data is as following:

```
var acf_data = new FormData();
acf_data.append("fields[terms]", [7111, 7106]);
```

I expect it to show all the ids selected in relationship field.